# Adding Cartesian Axis to Polar Plot to Replicate the Y Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created a Polar Chart which is essentially a wind rose. It uses directional degrees for the theta value and wind speed for the height. This visualization is being used within Power BI so I have some limitations. In the Power BI page there are about a half dozen of these wind roses on a page that are all pretty small so when the Label for the y-axis is in there it looks rather crowded. I would love to be able to add a Cartesian axis to the polar plot above and to the side where it would label them outside the circle.

Basically something like this
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFkHN.png)

When I try and use fig to add it it just never shows up and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code for the wind rose (there is some stuff for Power BI in there). This is really my first time using matplotlib so if you notice anything else done non-optimally I'd love to hear it.

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(WindSpeed, WindDir)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
theta = dataset.WindDir
heights = dataset.WindSpeed

plt.rcParams.update({
    "savefig.facecolor": (0.0, 0.0, 0, 0),  # black with alpha = 0%
})

# Get an axes handle/object
ax1 = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Plot
bars = ax1.bar(theta, heights,
        color='#9DD9D2',
        width=0.5,
        bottom=0.0,
        edgecolor='#666666',
        alpha=0.5)

## Main tweaks
# Radius limits
#ax1.set_ylim(0, 1.5)

# Radius tick position in degrees
#ax1.set_yticklabels([])
# Angle ticks
ax1.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2.0*np.pi, 17)[:-1])
# Set N to the top of the graph
ax1.set_theta_zero_location("N")
# Set Clockwise
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Set cardinal directions instead of degrees
ax1.set_xticklabels(['N', 'NNW', 'NW', 'WNW', 'W', 'WSW', 'SW', 'SSW', 'S', 'SSE', 'SE', 'ESE','E', 'ENE', 'NE', 'NNE'])
# Set Axis Text
ax1.tick_params(colors='#666666', labelsize=11, pad=10)
# Additional Tweaks
plt.grid(True)

ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.tight_layout()

# Generate Graph
plt.show()
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605137/matplotlib-polar-plot-radial-axis-offset/52337751#52337751) shows an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JohanC for providing me with a link to a pretty good explanation I was able to make my own. Still tweaking a few things but this gets the base of what I want with a polar plot and a Cartesian line offset.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
theta = dataset.WindDir
heights = dataset.WindSpeed

CIRCLE_RES = 36 # resolution of circle inside
def offset_radial_axis(ax):
    x_circle = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, CIRCLE_RES)
    y_circle = np.zeros_like(x_circle)
    ax.fill(x_circle, y_circle, fc='white', ec='black', zorder=2) # circle
    # or set the ticks manually (simple)
    # or define a custom TickLocator (very flexible)
    # or leave out this line if the ticks are fully behind the circle

X_OFFSET = .05 # to control how far the scale is from the plot (axes coordinates)
def add_scale(ax):
    # add extra axes for the scale
    rect = ax.get_position()
    rect = (rect.xmin-X_OFFSET, rect.ymin+rect.height/2, # x, y
            rect.width, rect.height/2) # width, height
    scale_ax = ax.figure.add_axes(rect)
    # hide most elements of the new axes
    for loc in ['right', 'top', 'bottom']:
        scale_ax.spines[loc].set_visible(False)
    scale_ax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
    scale_ax.patch.set_visible(False) # hide white background
    # adjust the scale
    scale_ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(*ax.get_ylim())
    scale_ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
    scale_ax.set_ylim(ax.get_rorigin(), ax.get_rmax())

def add_scale2(ax):
    # add extra axes for the scale
    rect = ax.get_position()
    rect = (rect.xmin-X_OFFSET, rect.ymin, # x, y
            rect.width, rect.height/2) # width, height
    scale_ax = ax.figure.add_axes(rect)
    # hide most elements of the new axes
    for loc in ['right', 'top', 'bottom']:
        scale_ax.spines[loc].set_visible(False)
    scale_ax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
    scale_ax.patch.set_visible(False) # hide white background
    # adjust the scale
    scale_ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(*ax.get_ylim())
    scale_ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
    scale_ax.set_ylim(ax.get_rmax(), ax.get_rorigin())

# Plot
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.bar(theta, heights,
    color='#00828C',
    width=0.5,
    bottom=0.0,
    edgecolor='#666666',
    alpha=0.5)

# Radius tick position in degrees
ax.set_yticklabels([])
# Angle ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2.0*np.pi, 17)[:-1])
# Set N to the top of the graph
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
# Set Clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Set cardinal directions instead of degrees
ax.set_xticklabels(['N', 'NNW', 'NW', 'WNW', 'W', 'WSW', 'SW', 'SSW', 'S', 'SSE', 'SE', 'ESE','E', 'ENE', 'NE', 'NNE'])
# Set Axis Text
ax.tick_params(colors='#666666', labelsize=11, pad=10)
# Additional Tweaks
ax.grid(True)

add_scale(ax)
add_scale2(ax)

plt.show()
```

And the resulting image:

[Polar Plot Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skk3N.png)