# How to customize a sector in a polar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I only want a portion of the polar plot so that the information in the plot can be more prominent. Is there any good way?

The red box below is the part I want to keep

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.scatter(np.deg2rad([75, 85, 95, 105]), [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4], s=20,
           c='navy', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_thetamin(40)
ax.set_thetamax(140)
ax.set_rmax(6)
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `rorigin`?

Comment: Haven't tried this method yet. Is there any documentation on this method? @Redox

Comment: Added the updated code... is that what you are looking for? Some documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the origin by using negative `rorigin()` numbers. Also, adjust theata min/max. See if this will work.
Note though that the start/origin will not change, just make it to the shape you need...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.scatter(np.deg2rad([75, 85, 95, 105]), [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4], s=20, c='navy', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_thetamin(70) ## Changed min/max
ax.set_thetamax(110)
ax.set_rmax(6)
ax.set_rorigin(-10) ## Add rorigin
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's the shape I want. But I wish the distance scale hadn't changed, is that OK?

Comment: Don't believe there is a simple way to do that. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605137/matplotlib-polar-plot-radial-axis-offset) - second answer. You may need to manually build the plot like that. See if that is what you are looking for